# Kubernetes / Rancher 2, mongo-replicaset with Local Storage Volume deployment

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, rancher, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pod

I try, I try, but Rancher 2.1 fails to deploy the "**mongo-replicaset**" Catalog App, with **Local Persistent Volumes** configured.

How to correctly deploy a mongo-replicaset with Local Storage Volume? Any debugging techniques appreciated since I am new to rancher 2.

I follow the 4 ABCD steps bellow, but the first pod deployment never ends. What's wrong in it? Logs and result screens are at the end. Detailed configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/16298).

**Note**: Deployment without Local Persistent Volumes **succeed**.

**Note**: Deployment with Local Persistent Volume and with the "mongo" image **succeed** (without replicaset version).

**Note**: Deployment with both mongo-replicaset and with Local Persistent Volume **fails**.

---

**Step A - Cluster**

Create a rancher instance, and:

1. Add three nodes: a worker, a worker etcd, a worker control plane
2. Add a label on each node: name one, name two and name three for node Affinity

---

**Step B - Storage class**

Create a storage class with these parameters:

1. volumeBindingMode : WaitForFirstConsumer [saw here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local)
2. name : local-storage

---

**Step C - Persistent Volumes**

Add 3 persistent volumes like this:

1. type : local node path
2. Access Mode: Single Node RW, 12Gi
3. storage class: local-storage
4. Node Affinity: name one (two for second volume, three for third volume)

---

**Step D - Mongo-replicaset Deployment**

From catalog, select Mongo-replicaset and configure it like that:

1. replicaSetName: rs0
2. persistentVolume.enabled: true
3. persistentVolume.size: 12Gi
4. persistentVolume.storageClass: local-storage

---

**Result**

After doing ABCD steps, the newly created mongo-replicaset app stay infinitely in "Initializing" state.

[image: mongo status stopped at initialized]

The associated mongo workload contain only one pod, instead of three. And this pod has two 'crashed' containers, bootstrap and mongo-replicaset.

[image: crashed workload with only one pod]

---

**Logs**

This is the output from the 4 containers of the only running pod. There is no error, no problem.

[image: no logs in mongo container]
[image: allmost no logs in copy-config container]
[image: allmost no logs in install container]
[image: some logs from bootstrap container]

I can't figure out what's wrong with this configuration, and I don't have  any tools or techniques to analyze the problem. Detailed configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/16298). Please ask me for more commands results.

Thanks you

Comment: What does `kubectl describe rs mongo-replicaset` say?

Comment: Error from server (NotFound): replicasets.extensions "mongo-replicaset" not found. I try with mongodb-replicaset (the name of the workload?) but it's the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All this configuration is correct.

It's missing a detail since Rancher is a containerized deployment of kubernetes.
Kubelets are deployed on each node in docker containers. They don't access to OS local folders.

It's needed to add a volume binding for the kubelets, like that K8s will be able to create the mongo pod with this same binding.

In rancher:
Edit the cluster yaml (Cluster > Edit > Edit as Yaml)

Add the following entry under "services" node:

```
  kubelet: 
    extra_binds: 
      - "/mongo:/mongo:rshared"
```

Comment: Just for clarification: go to Cluster Management => then 3 dots menu => Edit Config => Edit as Yaml . I was able to apply modification only that way.
Direct "Edit YAML" from menu didn't work for me( some strange { "data": "404 page not found\n" } error occured )
Thank you.